# Why is assignment of a variable in an UPDATE statement not transactional?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the book "T-SQL Fundamentals", for the "UPDATE" with "assignment" query below, the author stated:

> The specialized UPDATE syntax is run as a transaction, and it’s more
>   efficient than using separate UPDATE and SELECT statements because it
>   accesses the data only once. Note that variable assignment isn’t
>   transactional, though.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MySequences
(
    id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_MySequences PRIMARY KEY(id),
    val INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dbo.MySequences VALUES('SEQ1', 0); 

DECLARE @nextval AS INT;
UPDATE dbo.MySequences
    SET @nextval = val += 1
WHERE id = 'SEQ1';
SELECT @nextval AS nextValue;
```

I'm a little bit confused as to why "UPDATE" statement is run as a transaction, but the variable assignment (i.e. `SET @nextval = val +`= 1) isn't transactional? Isn't the variable assignment part of the "UPDATE" statement?

Could someone please clarify the concept?

Comment: ACID properties of databases apply to tables, not to scalar variables.

Comment: thank you very much for the comment. So I was just wondering, what happen if the "UPDATE" transaction fails and how will the failure affect "SELECT @nextval AS nextValue"? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If this is actual code (and not just a sample to frame a question), I'd suggest using an actual sequence (introduced in SQL 2012). Or at the very least an identity value. What you've got now is likely to have problems...

Comment: The short answer is "by design". And by the way, table variables are also non-transactional, it's not just about scalars.

Comment: Since there's no point in rolling back a variable. It only exists while you run the code anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be transactional because `it's recursive update`. But each recursive run is under implicit transaction.

It means update first row by my variable, and add to my variable old value +1, then second run update second row, add to my variable old value +1...

If you would like atomic solution use rownumber or sequency.If you would like to use transaction `use explicit transaction`.